# .net Frameworks compatibility

Tags: c#, vb.net

I Create A new application in the framework 4.5 and i have an older application was created in 1.1 framework , i want to call a form that exist in the new application from the old one .
 i already try to load The executable application file  using the assembly class ,  Assembly.loadfrom() that i used before and works fine between 2 different application, that have same frameworks , Now an exception  was thrown that the Assembly is  invalid 
the question is it's possible to call an new Assembly from an older one 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the old application has been loaded using an older version of .NET that doesn't support the newer assembly, then no. It's a bit like trying to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit operating system.

The simplest solution would probably be to rebuild the old application to target .NET 4.5 instead.